# MediaPlayer pause() behaviour

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using a `MediaPlayer` to stream audio from a URL.

According to the documentation, calling the `MediaPlayer` `pause` followed by a `play` will resume from the point where it was paused.

I am wondering how this works with a live audio stream.  When I call `pause` is the `MediaPlayer` creating some sort of buffer of all the incoming data, and storing it until I call `play` again?

If this is indeed the case, is there a max size on this buffer?  I am mainly concerned about a user pausing the `MediaPlayer` and it using a lot of memory while it stores incoming audio data.

Comment: No, pausing a live stream and playing again will only resume it from the live state. It will not keep a buffer of all the information since it was paused.

Comment: This isn't the behavior I was seeing when I was testing it.  I was streaming from my app, and from my computer (for reference) simultaneously.  I paused the stream on my phone, waited a few minutes, and when I resumed it definitely was not as the same point as my computer (which I had never paused).

Comment: I've done a lot of streaming hls. Streams are not always exactly in the same place (look at Twitch for example on Android and desktop) but the MediaPlayer does not buffer 25 minutes of video while it's paused. Hmm..now you have me wondering if I did something special.

Comment: I have experienced similar behavior with the pause functionality. My first thought was to decrease the default value of MediaPlayer buffer. But unfortunately that's not possible as its deep down somewhere in the architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As, I understand you are using Mediaplayer for streaming audio from a URL.. something like radio channels. In this process, you are using buffers. So, the behaviour you are getting is quite obvious. When you pause, your data will continue to store and on resuming the stream, it will start from the point it was paused.

But streaming should not behave in this manner unlike stored audio which start from the point it was paused. Streaming audio should always start from the live streaming at that point. So, onPause, you should free the buffers. When the user resumes again, you can restart the stream the way you did it first time. This is how the behavior should be.

If you check out, normal radio streaming is implemented in most of the radio streaming apps.

Comment: So you're saying there is a buffer, and that I can free it manually ?

Comment: If you have defined your own buffers in application for storing some data before starting the playback, then you need to free that. Else if you are just using MediaPlayer instance, then free the resources and onResume restart Mediaplayer the way you did it first time. I understand in that case it will take little time while resume the way it takes the first time, but that should be fine as it is connecting to live stream again.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends .. What I mean is that rather than pausing the stream, stop the stream. Next time recreate and play the stream.

Comment: So in other words, **Pausing** the stream creates a buffer, and **Stopping** the stream does not?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: online radio channels works with the same way, you have to use buffer and then they are played from that buffer, i.e you can't pause the audio which is being played from the audio stream from url, pls check this link i have developed the android application for this site http://www.xgradio.com/

Comment: @ManishYadav .. Thats correct Manish. Even my music player in google play (Fusion Music Player - It has Shoutcast radio integrated in it) is based on the principle I mentioned above.

Comment: @sushil thats great can i have ur gtalk id :)

Comment: @ManishYadav .. my gmail id is mentioned in my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: sorry buddy i can't see any contact details :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49527/discussion-between-sushil-and-manish-yadav)

Comment: @Sushil  i m  facing same issue in case of video once i pause and then unable to resume the video